# In bash, how can I display the output of a command ONLY if there is an error?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a build script in which, at some point, I call `make -j4`. I don't want to see its entire output every time, though; except when there is an error. So how can I buffer the output of make and print it if it returns a non-zero result?

Comment: If there is an error, it will be on stderr.  Just do `make -j4 > /dev/null`

Comment: What I tried to achieve was to show the entire output upon error, not only what was on stderr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

save the output in a variable - and print on error

```
cmdout=$(make -j4 2>&1)
es=$?
if ((es)); then
  echo >&2 "make error es $es: \"$cmdout\""
else
  echo "make success"
fi
```

Comment: Is `if ((es)); then` part correct? Should it be `$es`?

Comment: In arithmetic conditionals ((...)) you can only use variables with integer values and the dollar sign "$" is optional - another difference from [[ ... ]] is  no need for a leading and trailing space inside ((...))

Comment: There are some exceptions though, e.g. x=13; ((16#x == 19)) && echo equal || echo unequal
-bash: ((: 16#x: value too great for base (error token is "16#x")

Comment: Would `cmdout=$(make -j4 2>&1)` remove the color from the output, by the way?

Comment: Color should be coming from xterm color escape sequences - I would think color is preserved - cmdout=$(echo "tickle me pink"|grep --color=always pink); echo "cmdout \"$cmdout\"" - works for me

Comment: You can simplify: `if cmdout=$(make -j4 2>&1); then ...` is equivalent (but inverted).

Comment: OK my point was that `isatty` sometimes decides that `$(command)` is not a terminal, and the program then avoids color formatting. To have the colors as well I did something along the lines of `cmdout=$(script -q -c "make -j4 2>&1" | cat)`

Answer (score 4):

Save the output to a temporary file

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
make -j4 &> "$tmp"
```

and only show it if there was an error

```
if (( $? )) ; then
    cat "$tmp"
fi
rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: Can the same behavior be achieved without creating an external file?

Comment: You can store the output in a variable, too, by `output=$(make -j4 2>&1)`. But it can get quite large.